# Android dialog dismiss() doesn't close

Tags: android, android-dialog

The custom dialog does dismiss at certain points in my program, for example when they press an "Edit" button, but the dialog will not dismiss if I select something from a list view and press an "Add" button. Both buttons end up using this same code below, but the if statements decide which will execute. Either way, the problem is that pcDialog.dismiss() is outside of the if statements, so it should dismiss always...but it doesn't.

Any ideas on what the problem might be? My dialog is declared outside of any methods as a member.

```
createDoneBtn.setOnClickListener(
                new View.OnClickListener() 
                {   
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(View v) 
                    {
                        if ( !editingPC )
                        {
                            ...
                        }
                        else if ( editingPC )
                        {
                            ...
                        }
                        adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
                        pcDialog.dismiss();
                    }
                });
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Maybe this one dismisses ok, but your code makes a second one to immediately appear?
Or maybe an exception is thrown but gets silently caught so you never step into `dismiss()` ?

Comment: Thanks, putting it in try caught a silent one.

Comment: @ShrimpCrackers you save my day)

Answer (score 1):

Why not first debug?

And I think it's best practice to put it in try - catch - finally. Then you can call dismiss in the finally.

Comment: In this example though it seems putting a catch close did harm instead  of being useful.